# Image infinite loop via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a little advertisement module for a client. They need a container to show a different image/link every 30 seconds. The container (div) will automatically have all of the ads loaded into it and the function should then take care of the rest.

My idea is as follows:

1. Pass selector to the custom function below
2. Hide all of the images within the selector
3. Add a class called "current_link" to the first image and then fade it in
4. Run a loop on the images array (variable called "links") and use the delay and queue jQuery functions to queue the images with a delay to show after eachother.
5. The queue function will remove the current_link of the active ad, fade it out, add a the class to the next image and fade it in.

Needless to say, it's not working that well :D At this stage with the little functionality it does do, it does not loop infinantely (ads should loop and not stop).

Any advice on how to improve on the code (I'm far from an expert) would greatly be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

### [Checkout the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dTfh/)

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="advert_list">
      <a href="" target="_Blank"><img src="someimage1.png" /></a>
      <a href="" target="_Blank"><img src="someimage2.png" /></a>
 </div> <!-- e/o -->
```

**jQuery:**

```
 // Advertisement loader
    $.fn.image_fader = function(user_options) {

        // Image container
        var container = this;
        
        // All links:
        var links = $(container).find("a");

        // Default options:
        var default_options = {
            path: "",
            duration: 30000
        };

        // Create combined options:
        var options = $.extend(default_options, user_options);

        // Hide all images:
        $(links).hide();
        
        // Show first image:
        $(links).first().addClass("current_link").fadeIn();

        // Run the loop on the images:
        $(links).each(function() {
            
            // current link:
            var current_loop_link = this;
            
            $(current_loop_link).delay(options.duration).queue(function(next) {
                
                // Fade out any of the previous links:
                $(".current_link").fadeOut();
                
                // Add class to next link:
                $(current_loop_link).addClass("current_link");
                
                // Fade in the next link:
                $(current_loop_link).fadeIn();
                
                next();
            });
        });
    }

 // Call to above function:
 $(".advert_list").image_fader();
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for same?

Comment: You don't need the `$()` around `links`, it is a jQuery collection already.

Comment: also, you should get into the habit of prefixing jQuery collections with `$`, so `links` would become `$links` (We know its a jquery collection just by looking at its name)

Comment: @Bergi and JustAnil: Thank you for the advice! Out of curiousity, what is the difference between a collection and array? I was under the impression it returns an array (when example using find())

Comment: It's only an array-like object (with numeric properties and a `.length`), but it does not inherit from `Array.prototype` - try `$(…) instanceof Array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how your current function does an endless queue that changes between images. You're only setting up a 2-item (delay, callback, fadeout) queue for each of the links independently.

Use a dedicated function that is repeatedly called instead:

```
$.fn.image_fader = function(user_options) {
    var links = $(this).find("a"),
        default_options = {
            path: "",
            duration: 30000
        },
        // Create combined options:
        options = $.extend(default_options, user_options);

    links.hide();

    // Show first image:
    show(links.first());

    function show(link) {
        link.addClass("current_link")
          .fadeIn()
          .delay(options.duration)
          .queue(function(next) {
             link.fadeOut().removeClass("current_link");
             // determine next one and move on:
             show(links.eq( (links.index(link)+1) % links.length ));
             next(); // dequeue
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bergi, thank you, this worked like a charm and makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 1):

try this

**http://jsfiddle.net/s7GzJ/1/**

```
<script>

// define plugin
(function($){ 
    // Advertisement loader
    $.fn.image_fader = function(user_options) {

        // Image container
        var container = $(this);

        // All links:
        var links = container.find("a");
        var linkI = -1;

        // Default options:
        var default_options = {
            path: "",
            duration: 2000
        };

        // Create combined options:
        var options = $.extend(default_options, user_options);

        //show next
        var show = function(){
            linkI ++;
            if( linkI >= links.size()) linkI = 0;

            links.eq(linkI).fadeIn(500, delay);
        };

        // dummy animation for delaying current one
        var delay = function(){
            links.eq(linkI).animate({opacity:100}, options.duration , hide).addClass("current_link");

        };

        // hide current
        var hide = function(){
            links.eq(linkI).hide(500, function(){
                $(this).removeClass("current_link");
                show();
            });
        };

        // Hide all images:
        $(links).hide();

        // start show first
        show();

    }
})(jQuery);  

//call plugin
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Call to above function:
    $(".advert_list").image_fader();
}); 

</script>
```